# Place image in ngFor at start of each row in ionic

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I am trying to display images beginning at the left of each row in an ngFor. The images are displaying successfully, however, in 1 row if there is only one image and the same with another the images are placed on opposite sides. For example row 1 image at left and row 2 large gap and image at right [image: example].

html file

```
         <ion-icon class="ion-icon1" name="calendar"></ion-icon>
         <ion-card [ngClass]="note.card ? 'card-item' : 'no-card' ">
            <ion-card-header>
               <b>Date:</b> {{note?.Created}}
            </ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-content [ngClass]="isMenuOpen[i] ? 'active' : 'inactive'" *ngFor='let ind of individuals'>

               <ion-list>
                  <b>Injury: </b> {{ind?.InjuryType}}
               </ion-list>

               <ion-row class="ion-align-items-start">
                  <ion-col size="6" *ngFor='let img of pImages'>
                     <div *ngIf="img" class="ion-align-self-start">
                       <span *ngIf="note.noteID === img.NoteID">
                          <img src="http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/{{img.Image}}" (click)="photoLarge(img.Image)" />
                       </span>
                     </div>
                  </ion-col>
               </ion-row>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
     </timeline-item>
 </timeline>
```

Comment: can you try it inside ion-card instead of ion-row because it act like grid

Comment: Hi it is inside a card sorry for I never added the code above

Comment: can you post your code as sample\

Comment: Edited above thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use display property of css. Like below in ngStyle

```
<span  [ngStyle]="{'display':note.noteID === img.NoteID?'block':'none'} ">
     <img src="http://ccoulter12.lampt.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/{{img.Image}}" (click)="photoLarge(img.Image)" />
</span>
```